# How to add custom icon in Arc Map 10.1?

Tags: arcmap, arcgis-10.1

I have created cell_tower icon in .emf format and inserted in Arc Map 10.1. I want to apply this icon as symbol to point layer.

I am trying but I guess I am doing something wrong.

Tried following things:

1.Going though following links/articles :

[Creating new styles](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Creating_new_styles/00s60000000r000000/) , [Adding custom north arrow](http://mappingcenter.esri.com/index.cfm?fa=ask.answers&q=27)

2.Created new style (with the help of customize tool) but unable to add icon as EMF file.

3.Searching on Google.

Any help will be great !!! Thanks in advance : )

Software : ArcGIS for Desktop 10.1

Screenshot : [image: screenshot]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use a custom icon:

- Click on the icon in the Table of Contents (not on the name).
- Click the edit Symbol button.
- From  the "Type" dropdown select "Picture Marker Symbol"
- Browse to the emf-file.

If this does not work, then your file is probably too large.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be able to do this as a [Picture Marker Symbol](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000002000000) for which *.emf is one of the supported formats.